# What is a good method when writing packages to handle the no visible global function definition for stats functions?

Tags: r, namespaces, cran, roxygen2

I am writing an R package for CRAN, which now throws errors such as

```
cluster.phrases: no visible global function definition for ‘par’
```

It helpfully suggests:

```
Consider adding
      importFrom("grDevices", "grey", "rgb")
      importFrom("graphics", "abline", "arrows", "axis", "image", "legend",
                 "lines", "matplot", "par", "points", "text")
to your NAMESPACE file.
```

It basically wants the graphics package namespace to be imported.  Fine.  But I am building the package in RStudio, and documenting with ROxygen which automatically builds the NAMESPACE file.  So manually adding these lines seems wrong.

What is the proper fix here?  I would very much like to avoid putting "graphics::par" and whatnot everywhere in my code as that will make it far less readable.

Comment: Adding `#' @importFrom package function1 function2 etc.` will generate those lines when you re oxygenize your package.

Comment: And you have to do this with each function? Is there any way to automate this process?  Or do it globally?  Due to using graphics, grDevices, and stats regularly, that's a lot of functions to wade through!

Comment: You can import an entire package's namespace using `#' @import package` but that is unnecessary if you're actually only using one or two functions. It is not possible to automate because functions could come from anywhere - resolving that ambiguity is part of your task as a package developer.